# Google Api v4 sheets query with conditions

Tags: google-api, conditional-statements, where-clause, google-sheets-api

Hi I would like to know how to include conditions in a Google Api v4 sheets query.

e.g. where B = 'News

Do I include the condition in the range or as an additional request parameter?

I am currently using

GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values:batchGet

and

POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values:batchUpdate

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no ready-made query() function in Sheets v4. What you can do is fetch the values of a given range in sheets using [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) then loop over the values and compare. Sample is found in [Basic Reading in Sheetsv4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading#read_a_single_range).

Aside from that try this [vlookup method](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/36A0epDlIdE/discussion). However, it uses Apps Script.